# NPM - Cordova and logging into Facebook

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm wondering what the best way to generate a Facebook login process would be if I created a Cordova/phonegap project using npm.

A bunch of the Phonegap Facebook plugins appear to be broken or outdated.  I've spent probably 3-4 hours trying to create a working 'login' example that doesn't require using a URL (since the Phonegap/Cordova application will be an 'app', not a website).

Basically, is there any easy way to receive an access_token or any useful 'token' in Cordova/Phonegap?  Again, the app is not a 'Web' App, so there will be no URLs to point to.

Thanks, guys (and gals)!

Comment: You must use a plugin, this is the only way to use Facebook native mobile sdk for mobile platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin You'll have to install it yourself to your generated project.

Comment: The plugin also supports PhoneGap Build, if you don't want to faff around with the PhoneGap CLI or native stuff yourself.